# Transferring live iPhone app from existing apple developer account to another account with gap period

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iphone-developer-program

We have a live iPhone app on apple store. By mistake initially we gave the wrong company name existing developer account. Now we have created a new apple developer account with correct company name. Now we want to transfer our existing live app from our old account to new account. Is it possible to do it with have a gap period? What i have read is that first i have to remove the app from old account, then i have to submit the app from the new account for approval and after approval it will go live. but this would have a approval gap of 10-15 days. is it possible to without gap period. Can i simply change the name and submit?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is leave the current app online. Submit the new one to the store and set the option that it should be release not automatically but manually by developer. When the app is approved and ready for sale you can take you old app offline and release the new to the store.

Comment: I think this should work. Let me try and i will get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: But is it possible to submit app for approval with same name as another live app?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your company name by contacting the Apple Support. This may be much easier then transferring the app to another account.